# Combining SELECT Statements to connect Inventory SKU array/list to Product Page SKUs

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Is this possible with one statement?

Multiple tables in my database.

Using this `SELECT` to retrieve an array of sub-sku's (aka product listing sku's)

```
SELECT SKU FROM MasterSKU WHERE '4048' IN (AltSKU, SKU_1, SKU_2, SKU_3);
```

Returns

```
+-------------------+
|        SKU        |
+-------------------+
| 4048              |
| 4048-SET-15       |
| 4699-4528-4048-EA |
+-------------------+
```

The actual SKU is `4048` and the result set is all the product listing sku's connected to this one sku.

These SKU's are located in a few other tables and generated by an eCommerce API.

This is my second `SELECT` statement to return where (what channel) the SKUs are located and the associated ItemID.

```
(SELECT 'store_1' as channel, SKU, ItemID  FROM Listings_store1 WHERE SKU = '4048')
    UNION
(SELECT 'store_2', SKU, ItemID  FROM Listings_store2 WHERE SKU = '4048')
    UNION
(SELECT 'store_3', SKU, ItemID  FROM Listings_store3 WHERE SKU = '4048')
    UNION
(SELECT 'store_4', SKU, ItemID  FROM Listings_store4 WHERE SKU = '4048');
```

This results in

```
+----------+-------------------+---------------+
| channel  |        SKU        |    ItemID     |
+----------+-------------------+---------------+
| store_1  | 4048              | 5654515256454 |
| store_1  | 4048-SET-15       | 5654515234536 |
| store_3  | 4699-4528-4048-EA | 5654515243553 |
+----------+-------------------+---------------+
```

How I'm doing it now is in PHP to turn the first SELECT statement into an array, and then looping the results to retrieve the results. Something like `for ($i = 0; $i < $channelskucount; $i++) { $channeldetectquery = "(SELECT  'store_1' as source, SKU FROM Listings_store1 WHERE SKU = '$channelskuarray[$i]') . . .`

Is it possible, or feasible, to merge these two queries? As the first select statement normally acts as an array I loop over with the second in PHP, I'm not sure where to begin.

End output something like

```
+--------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+
| InventorySKU | channel  |        SKU        |    ItemID     |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+
|         4048 | store_1  | 4048              | 5654515256454 |
|         4048 | store_1  | 4048-SET-15       | 5654515234536 |
|         4048 | store_3  | 4699-4528-4048-EA | 5654515243553 |
+--------------+----------+-------------------+---------------+
```

Any tips/help really appreciated. I realize my first table isn't exactly normalized, but trying to finalize my first big database project so I've learned and am learning a lot along the way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is certainly possible [to do it in one query] if you do a minor, and much needed, restructuring of your data.  In fact, your issue perfectly illuminates the problem with the current structure.  The listings for the different stores shouldn't each have their own data table.  There should be a 'store' table which has columns for an id key, store name, store description, address, etc.  Then you would just have a single 'Listings' table with one additional column, the look-up (a foreign key relationship) to the id key of the 'store' table, followed by the rest of whatever is already there (sku, ItemID, etc.).  Shouldn't be hard to do, and you'll only have to do it once.  You could create the table and just brute force it:

```
INSERT into Listings (StoreID, SKU, ItemID,...)
    SELECT 1, SKU, ItemID,... FROM Listings1
INSERT into Listings (StoreID, SKU, ItemID,...)
    SELECT 2, SKU, ItemID,... FROM Listings2
...
```

Or do it the inexcusably lazy way for which I should be severely reprimanded for even mentioning (you should definitely double-check your column data types afterward and add indexes):

```
SELECT 1 as StoreID, * 
    INTO Listings
    FROM Listings1
UNION
SELECT 2, *
UNION
SELECT 3, *
UNION
SELECT 4, *
...
```

You then simply JOIN this table to the master_sku and store tables...  Like this:

```
DECLARE @InventorySKU as varchar(20)
SET @InventorySKU = '4084'

SELECT @InventorySKU as InventorySKU, s.StoreName as channel, l.SKU, l.ItemID
    FROM Listings l
    INNER JOIN MasterSKU ms on ms.SKU = l.SKU
    INNER JOIN Stores s on s.ID = l.StoreID
    WHERE 
        ms.AltSKU LIKE '%' + @InventorySKU + '%' OR
        ms.SKU_1 LIKE '%' + @InventorySKU + '%' OR
        ms.SKU_2 LIKE '%' + @InventorySKU + '%' OR
        ms.SKU_3 LIKE '%' + @InventorySKU + '%'
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Aww yeah. Thank you for the response. I do realize now the entire structure of my database is not optimized whatsoever (as I said, it was built on-the-fly with little knowledge about MySQL or any database system.. let alone proper schema, structure, normalization techniques, so forth). At the time it was built off my own personal ideas about how it could just *work*. Now it's grown to a whopping 29 Tables and over 400,000 Rows... and its functionalities work around a deep mass of PHP scripts with this current structure. I want to restructure, plan to, but time isn't allowing it at the moment.

Comment: @bbruman - It shouldn't be too hard to put it right (and it will open up a lot of other possible ways to easily query the data too).  Just copy/paste that bit of a code and over-write the numbers.  You could save the script too in case you had to do it again.  Feel free to 'Accept' the answer if it helped you.  Thanks.

Comment: @bbruman - I added a second way to build the mutli-store Listings table.

Comment: Brilliant thank you. Yes I was torn as your original answer is a better solution than my actual question :) Going to play around with the (hopefully temporary) alternative/band-aid solution for now as I'm crunched at the moment. Will accept shortly!

Comment: Going to plan out a restructure soon on local.. it's not the restructuring that will be the hardest part I think, but all the functionality and scripts built around it! Again, a fault (or maybe learning process is a better word ;)) of my own naivety